# UnrecognizedPropertyException while reading a yaml file

Tags: java, web-services, yaml, dropwizard

While working with dropwizard,

My dropwizard service reads the config.yml file.

```
public void run() throws Exception {
    this.run(new String[] { "server", "src/main/resources/config.yml" });
}
```

Config.yml file :

```
database:
  # the name of your JDBC driver
  driverClass: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

  # the username
  user: user2connect

  # the password
  password: password2connect

  # the JDBC URL
  url: jdbc:mysql://url.to.connect:port
```

But, I am getting an error as soon as the file is read -

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "database" (class com.service.config.DropWizardConfiguration), not marked as ignorable (4 known properties: , "http", "httpConfiguration", "logging", "loggingConfiguration"])
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.service.config.DropWizardConfiguration["database"])
```

After going through few topics, I realized that this might be causing because of Jackson is not able to ignore few properties.

I tried couple of things -

1) Added annotation @JsonIgnoreProperty (But not sure if I added it at expected place)

2) [Jackson how to ignore properties](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToIgnoreUnknown)

None of them helped. Can anyone point me what I might be missing here?

Comment: Can you post the code for your application configuration class?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

add the following lines to your configuration class

```
 @Valid
 @NotNull
 @JsonProperty
 private DataSourceFactory database = new DataSourceFactory();

 public DataSourceFactory getDataSourceFactory() {
    return database;
 }
```

Comment: Similar problem.  Adding the @JSonProperty fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

Probably your config class don't have the database, you need this property in your config class to parse .yml