# Unrecognized Field in Dropwizard YAML File

Tags: java, dropwizard

I'm getting the following error when launching a Dropwizard application that uses a database connection to MySQL:

```
app.yaml has an error:
* Unrecognized field at: database
  Did you mean?:
    - metrics
    - instanceId
    - logging
    - server
    - statsConfig
      [12 more]
```

At the end of my Dropwizard configuration file, I have the following:

```
database:
  driverClass: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
  user: ${MYSQL_USERNAME}
  password: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
  url: ${MYSQL_URL}
```

And in my configuration class, I have the following:

```
@Valid()
@NotNull()
@JsonProperty()
private static DataSourceFactory database;

public static DataSourceFactory getDatabase() {
  return database;
}

public static void setDatabase(final DataSourceFactory database) {
  AppConfig.database = database;
}
```

Several other complex configuration objects are loading correctly (it's a pretty big config file), but this one is not. Any ideas why I'm getting this error?

*EDIT* This question is similar to this one: [UnrecognizedPropertyException While Reading A YAML File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23395939/unrecognizedpropertyexception-while-reading-a-yaml-file). However, that solution didn't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** check the example application [here](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-example/src/main/java/com/example/helloworld/HelloWorldConfiguration.java#L53-L61) and [here](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-example/src/main/java/com/example/helloworld/HelloWorldConfiguration.java#L22-L24).

1. `@JsonProperty()` - there are extra brackets here.
2. `private static DataSourceFactory database;` - remove `static` from here. Reference [the docs](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.0.4/docs/manual/jdbi.html) for an example of how it should look.
3. Also add the `= new DataSourceFactory();` as per docs and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30079790/unrecognized-field-at-database-did-you-mean-metrics-server-logging).

I've checked on old version of `Dropwizard` and number 2 is your most immediate problem.