# How to get String from config.yml file in Dropwizard resource?

Tags: java, guice, dropwizard

I want to geta String in my Dropwizard `config.yml` and access it from a resource class.

I have added the class to the configuration

```
public class DropwizardBackendConfiguration extends Configuration {

  @NotEmpty
  private String uploadFileLocation;

  @JsonProperty
  public String getUploadFileLocation() {
    return uploadFileLocation;
  }

  @JsonProperty
  public void setUploadFileLocation(String uploadFileLocation) {
    this.uploadFileLocation = uploadFileLocation;
  }

}
```

I am able to get the content in the run method

```
 public void run(
      final DropwizardBackendConfiguration configuration, final Environment environment) {
...
 System.out.println(configuration.getUploadFileLocation());


}
```

But how can I get this value in my resource class.

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40660710/unrecognized-field-in-dropwizard-yaml-file)....Try this

Comment: I hope you have defined 'objectStorage' in SomeConfiguration.java file

Comment: Thanks for the tipp I added some notes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the complete `DropwizardBackendConfiguration` or just the `uploadFileLocation` in a Jersey Resource, you will have to pass it as a constructor argument.

The Getting Started guide [illustrates this with the `HelloWorldResource`](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.3.1/docs/getting-started.html#creating-a-resource-class). In this example there are two constructor arguments:

```
public HelloWorldResource(String template, String defaultName)
```

An instance of this class is [registered in the `run` method](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.3.1/docs/getting-started.html#registering-a-resource):

```
@Override
public void run(HelloWorldConfiguration configuration,
                Environment environment) {
    final HelloWorldResource resource = new HelloWorldResource(
        configuration.getTemplate(),
        configuration.getDefaultName()
    );
    environment.jersey().register(resource);
}
```

Do something similar using your configuration and your resource class.

Answer (score 0):

It may be probably late but you this can be done by dropwizard-guice dependency, this library used Google guice for dependency injection using annotations to configure Java objects. [As an extract from this article by Ricky Yim](https://dzone.com/articles/dropwizard-and-guice)

You could can inject the properties into the resource like below

```
package com.github.codingricky;

import com.google.inject.Inject; 
import com.google.inject.name.Named;
import javax.ws.rs.GET; 
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("/hello")
public class HelloResource { 
   private final String message;

   @Inject
   public HelloResource(@Named("message") String message) {
      this.message = message;
   }

   @GET
   public String hello() {
      return message;
   }
}
```

These values are picked from your .yml configuration using modules,

```
public class ServerModule implements Module { 
   @Override
   public void configure(Binder binder) {
   }

   @Provides
   @Named("message")
   public String provideMessage(ServerConfiguration serverConfiguration) {
      return serverConfiguration.getMessage();
   }
}
```

[Kindly look at the most recent library](https://github.com/HubSpot/dropwizard-guicier)

Comment: Thanks @Zoe , let me refactor